# OkHttpClient not supporting Http 1.1 for Https network calls

Tags: android, https, okhttp, http2

I am using Retrofit 2 with OkHttpClient. I want to make connection having the `keep-alive` property, so as to make persistent connection with the server which is Https enabled.

Now my problem arises when I am making a network call to Https end point the request follows Http2.0 protocol and the headers **Connection : keep-alive** are ignored, but when I make the same request to Http end point the headers are accepted and persistent connection works.
So to have Http1.1 protocol for Https calls I added manually this to my OkHttpClient.

```
 OkHttpClient.Builder okhttpclient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
 okhttpclient.protocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1));
```

But still the OkHttpClient sends a Http2.0 request to server for Https network calls.

I even tried to keep persistent connection on user end by using the 
[ConnectionPool](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ConnectionPool.html) class, but didn't find that as a good solution.

I also tried adding a sslSocketFactory to my OkHttpClient for Https requests. That too didn't work out.

**How should I force the Http1.1 protocol for my Https requests with OkHttpClient?**

Answer (score 0):

You’re correctly forcing OkHttp to use HTTP/1.1 with this line:

```
okhttpclient.protocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1));
```

Are you certain that the `OkHttpClient` produced by that builder is the one you’re using with your Retrofit instance?

Comment: Yes. My retrofit instance is singleton. The same request when sent to Http follows Http1.1 but when sending to Https follows Http2.0 on its own even after forcibly specifying the Http1.1 protocol.

Comment: This is surprising. If you can reproduce the problem in a small test case, please do and then report a bug against the OkHttp issue tracker.